# multiply two dictionaries values based on keys match

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries as:

`A=[{'a': 2, 'b': 3},{'a': 4, 'b': 5},{'b': 2,'c': 10,'d':8,'e': 9}]`
and

`B={'a':2,'b':3,'c':1,'d':8,'e':4}`

All I want to multiply values of keys `A` with values of keys `B` if keys get matched and if not then value will be zero for other keys
Expected:

`C=[{'a': 4, 'b': 9'},{'a': 8, 'b': 15},{'b': 6,'c': 10,'d':64,'e': 36}]`

I did as:

```
new_list=[]
for i in A:
    for k,v in i.items():
        for l,p in B.items():
            if k==l:
                new_d={k:v*p}
                new_list.append(new_d)
```

It doesn't seems to work. I'm looking for list comprehension approach!!!

Answer (score 4):

Using a nested list/dict comprehension. With `dict.get()`

**Ex:**

```
A=[{'a': 2, 'b': 3},{'a': 4, 'b': 5},{'b': 2,'c': 10,'d':8,'e': 9}]
B={'a':2,'b':3,'c':1,'d':8,'e':4}

result = [{k: B.get(k, 0)*v for k, v in i.items() } for i in A]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 4, 'b': 9}, {'a': 8, 'b': 15}, {'b': 6, 'c': 10, 'd': 64, 'e': 36}]
```

Comment: Vote up for this answer, this is the easiest way other than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use basic for loop:

```
A=[{'a': 2, 'b': 3},{'a': 4, 'b': 5},{'b': 2,'c': 10,'d':8,'e': 9}]
B={'a':2,'b':3,'c':1,'d':8,'e':4}
C = []

for dict in A:
    d = {}
    for key,val in dict.items():
        d.update({key:dict[key] * B[key]})
    C.append(d)

print (C)
```

output:

```
[{'a': 4, 'b': 9}, {'a': 8, 'b': 15}, {'b': 6, 'c': 10, 'd': 64, 'e': 36}]
```

what is equivalent to(list comprehension):

```
C = [{key: (dict[key]*B[key] if key in B else 0) for key, value in dict.items()} for dict in A]

print (C)
```

output:

```
[{'a': 4, 'b': 9}, {'a': 8, 'b': 15}, {'b': 6, 'c': 10, 'd': 64, 'e': 36}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
>>> A=[{'a': 2, 'b': 3},{'a': 4, 'b': 5},{'b': 2,'c': 10,'d':8,'e': 9}]
>>> B={'a':2,'b':3,'c':1,'d':8,'e':4}
>>> [{key: (value*B[key] if key in B else 0) for key, value in d.items()} for d in A]
[{'a': 4, 'b': 9}, {'a': 8, 'b': 15}, {'b': 6, 'c': 10, 'd': 64, 'e': 36}]
```